# IntelliJ Erlang "Unresolved macros"

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, intellij-14, eunit

**Setup:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2
Erlang plugin 0.11.1144
SDK: Erlang OTP 25, erts-13.0
Project Imported: https://github.com/FlowForwarding/enetconf
```

**Issue:**
When I mouse over some macros, I get the message "Unresolved macros '?debugMsg'", "Unresolved macros '?assertEqual'", etc. As a result, I am unable to do a code walk-through. Please help me in resolving the issue.

**Initial Debug:**
I see corresponding hrl files are included as listed below. But, when I mouseover the following line, I get a message "Unresolved include_lib: file not found". Looks like the hrl files are not included properly.

```
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
-include_lib("xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl").
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you report this issue at github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/issues Try to clear the IDE caches to see if it helps. (File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart) Make sure that content roots are properly configured jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

Comment: Thanks @Egor Klepikov. The issue got resolved after configuring Content roots

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after configuring Content roots as explained in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html. The ContentRoot looked as follows.

[image: Content Root]